# Animation in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have done one app in iOS before so I am relatively new.  I am going to be making an app which will have small squares moving across the screen.  I was wondering what the best way to draw a square as well as animate it would be for this purpose.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple approach using UIView

```
// Create a simple red box
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:v];

// The position we animate it to
frame.origin.x = 200;

// The actual animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    v.frame = frame;
}];
```